# form validations in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I tried implementing form validations as below:

I have form with name , password etc. for those textboxes we have so many validations like name shouldnot be numbers only, name shouldnot be all caps like we have nearly 15-20 validations for each textbox.

We implemented all these validation using patterns in angularjs. I wrote diff functions for each pattern. Is there any better way to implement so many validations for one textbox using angularjs

note: Please clarify better way only. What i have implemented seeems working fine but i want to know any other simply way for validations using angular

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by using "patterns" for validation? Do you mean the `ng-pattern` directive?

You should be using the `$validators` property on [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators):

```
.directive('validateName', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.validateName = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (viewValue === ...) {
          // run validation logic,
          // return true for valid
          return true;
        }

        // return false for invalid
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

and applying it to your inputs:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" validate-name>
```